Size of a drawing in tikz
When taking into account the width of a line, what is the actual size of a given drawing? For example, the command \draw (0,0) circle (2pt) obviously creates a circle with radius 2pt, but is this radius measured from the inside or outside of the line? Or perhaps the centre of the line?
Similarly, I can see a notable change between \fill (0,0) circle (2pt) and \filldraw (0,0) circle (2pt) since the latter includes the line around the edge of the fill... which of these two is actually of radius 2pt?

—, circle, … are path commands that create zero width paths. The path is then stoked (and/or filled) with the line width. In short, the path is the center of the line. Line width is added to the size(bounding box) of the tikzpicture to not crop half the line at the edges.

The circle (…) is deprecated for a long time. The newer syntax is circle[radius=…] (or x radius and y radius instead of the (… and …) syntax. Similar for the ellipse path operation and the arc path operation which uses start angle and end angle but also delta angle which the (…:…:… and …) syntax didn't support.

The radius is measured from the center of the circle to the middle of the line. You can see this by the following example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=20pt]
  \draw[cyan] (0,0) circle(20pt);
  \draw[red,line width=0.3pt] (30:10pt) -- (0,0) -- (20pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=20pt]
  \fill[cyan] (0,0) circle(20pt);
  \draw[red,line width=0.3pt] (30:10pt) -- (0,0) -- (20pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=20pt]
  \filldraw[fill=yellow,draw=cyan] (0,0) circle(20pt);
  \draw[red,line width=0.3pt] (30:10pt) -- (0,0) -- (20pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The case for \fill is different since line width has no effect on it.


Thanks that's helpful. I'm guessing \fill will then have the correct radius? Please could you add to your answer to show it?

All of them are "correct" ... when you say \path (0,0) circle[radius=20pt]; a "theoretical path", a circle with radius 20pt, is created. Then you can stroke it (drawing with a pen of a finite, nonzero width), fill it, or both things. Remember that \draw is the same as \path[draw], and so on.

BTW, the circle(20pt) syntax is deprecated... better use the new one.
